$P\{\omega\in \Omega : f(\omega)\geq a\} = 1 \ \forall a>0 \\ \Rightarrow P\{\omega\in \Omega : f(\omega)\geq a \ \forall a>0 \} = 1$
For context, I am currently trying to show that a function is equal to $\infty$ almost-surely, and I started wondering:
Could $$ P\{\omega\in \Omega : f(\omega)\geq a\} = 1 \ \forall a>0 $$ imply
$$ P\{\omega\in \Omega : f(\omega)\geq a \ \forall a>0 \} = 1 $$ ?
I would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

By continuity of measure we have $1=\lim_{a\uparrow \infty}P(f\geq a)=P(f=\infty)$. So $P(f\geq a,,\forall a>0)\geq P(f=\infty)=1$.

Monotonicity is your friend: The events $\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\ge a\}$ are nested:
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\ge a\}\subset \{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\ge b\},\qquad 0\le b<a.
$$
Because of this,
$$
\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\ge a,\forall a>0\}
=\cap_{a>0}\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\ge a\}
=\cap_{n=1}^\infty \{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\ge n\}.
$$
As Snoop indicates, if $P\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\ge a\}=1$ for all $a>0$ (equivalently, for all positive integers) then
$$
P\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\ge a,\forall a>0\}=\lim_{n\to\infty}P\{\omega\in\Omega: f(\omega)\ge n\}=1.
$$
